# Como faço para não selecionar dados repetidos que contenham em uma coluna, um valor especifico no SQL?

Tags: postgresql, select, sqlite

Boa noite pessoal, sou iniciante com Banco de Dados, tenho uma Query que executa um filtro seguindo uma regra:

**Regra:**

> **GSM** que for repetido, e tiver em ambos o **STATUS** = 'ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA' e seu **MOTIVO_ENVIO** for igual, importe apenas um registro, cuja **DATA_ALTERACAO** for mais recente.

Fiz o filtro da seguinte maneira:

```sql
select ex.[Nº Tel], ex.[Nº Contrato], ex.[Motivo de Envio], ex.[Status], ex.[Data Ativação], ex.[Data Importação], ex.[Data Alteração], ex.[CPF/CNPJ], ex.[IMEI], ex.[Usuário], ex.[Filiais], ex.[Descrição Anomalia]
from Sheet1 ex
where ex.[Status] = 'ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA'
and exists (
            select tmp.[Nº Tel]
            from Sheet1 tmp
            where tmp.[Nº Tel] = ex.[Nº Tel]
            and tmp.[Motivo de Envio] = ex.[Motivo de Envio]
            and tmp.[Status] = ex.[Status]
            group by tmp.[Nº Tel], tmp.[Motivo de Envio], tmp.[Status]
            having count(tmp.[Nº Tel]) > 1)
```

Irei dar um exemplo de como é para ser feito:

[image: Resultado]

Pode observar que o campo `GSM` está se repetindo, O campo `MOTIVO_ENVIO` também está se repetindo, o campo `STATUS` está com **'ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA'** e se repetindo, ou seja é o que preciso, só que dentre todos esses registros irei pegar o que está com a `DATA_ALTERACAO` mais recente, pois é isso que preciso.

Mas estou tendo um problema, o resultado me traz dados repetidos em que alguns registros estão com o `Status` que contenha os valores `('LIBERADO', 'PENDENTE', 'EM ANÁLISE', 'ANOMALIA DEFINITIVA')` e isso eu não posso ter.

Mas não é somente dar um `WHERE Status NOT IN ('LIBERADO', 'PENDENTE', 'EM ANÁLISE', 'ANOMALIA DEFINITIVA')` até porque isso somente iria remover o registro que contenha esse `Status`, eu preciso que remova todos os `Nº Tel` que tenha esses `Status`.

**Exemplo:**

```
     Nº Tel               Motivo de Envio                Status
_________________________________________________________________________
| 31994202248 | PRIMEIRA ATIVAÇÃO_REEMBOLSO - ADM | LIBERADO            |
| 31994202248 | PRIMEIRA ATIVAÇÃO_REEMBOLSO - ADM | ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA |
| 31994202248 | PRIMEIRA ATIVAÇÃO_REEMBOLSO - ADM | ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA |
```

Como visto acima o `Nº Tel` está se repetindo, o `Motivo de Envio` está igual, o `Status` está com **'ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA'** só que também está com **LIBERADO** ou seja, não preciso desses registros, no caso eles não podem aparecer no resultado final. Dei um exemplo com o `Status = 'LIBERADO'` mas o mesmo se aplica ao `Status = PENDENTE, EM ANÁLISE, ANOMALIA DEFINITIVA`

Alguém?

Comment: Pesquise pela cláusula DISTINCT: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-select-lists.html#QUERIES-DISTINCT

Comment: adicione o distinct ficando, SELECT DISTINCT (restante da query). veja se resolve

Comment: Isso não resolve meu problema, o `DISTINCT` irá fazer com que, por exemplo se eu tiver 5 dados repetidos ele irá me trazer somente um, isso não é o que preciso, a regra a qual preciso está informada no post com um exemplo para melhor explicar.

Comment: Seja mais claro sobre qual o resultado desejado.

Comment: @anonimo preciso criar essa Query para rodar corretamente no SQLite `Nº Tel que for repetido, e tiver em ambos o STATUS = 'ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA' e seu MOTIVO_ENVIO for igual, importe apenas um registro, cuja DATA_ALTERACAO for mais recente.` acho que fica mais fácil eu falar qual filtro é para ser feito do que por minha tentativa de fazer está query e tentar solucionar os problemas dela, com certeza você deve ter mais conhecimentos que eu no momento em SQL, se puder me ajudar mano, escrevendo está Query para mim, pois tentar eu tentei e muito, mas infelizmente não consegui!

Comment: @anonimo Editei minha pergunta, acrescentei mais exemplos fui o mais objetivo só que esclarecedor possível, espero que entenda! você encontra o exemplo aqui também [resultado](https://i.snag.gy/l0UPZv.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    ex.[Nº Tel],
    ex.[Nº Contrato],
    ex.[Motivo de Envio],
    ex.[Status],
    ex.[Data Ativação],
    ex.[Data Importação],
    ex.[Data Alteração],
    ex.[CPF/CNPJ],
    ex.[IMEI],
    ex.[Usuário],
    ex.[Filiais],
    ex.[Descrição Anomalia]
from Sheet1 ex
-- Inner que limita os resultados
inner join (
    select
        ex2.[Nº Tel], ex2.[Nº Contrato], max(ex2.[Data Alteração]) data_alteracao
    from Sheet1 ex2
    group by x2.[Nº Tel], ex2.[Nº Contrato]
) limite on limite.[Nº Tel] = ex.[Nº Tel] and limite.[Nº Contrato] = ex.[Nº Contrato] and limite.data_alteracao = ex.[Data Alteração]
-- FIM: Inner que limita os resultados
where ex.[Status] = 'ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA'
and exists (
    select tmp.[Nº Tel]
    from Sheet1 tmp
    where tmp.[Nº Tel] = ex.[Nº Tel]
        and tmp.[Motivo de Envio] = ex.[Motivo de Envio]
        and tmp.[Status] = ex.[Status]
        group by tmp.[Nº Tel], tmp.[Motivo de Envio], tmp.[Status]
        having count(tmp.[Nº Tel]) > 1
    )
```

Comment: não funcionou na verdade de 9 registros que era pra me retornar me retornou 45, sendo que se repetiram todos, mas mesmo se eles não se repetirem vai dar mais de 9 registros.

Comment: Veja se, por acaso eu não troquei algum critério sem querer. Não copie o meu, faça as alterações em cima do seu SQL. 
Execute o seu primeiro e depois modifique, pq eu ainda acho que estas alterações podem resolver o problema

Comment: O que você fez de diferente foi por o **MAX** e acrescentar o **GROUP BY** ao final, se eu tirar esse GROUP BY e deixar o MAX me retorna só um registro, se eu tirar o MAX e deixar o GROUP BY me retorna 45 igual antes, então não deu muita diferença, eu tenho um outra Query que faz isso exatamente mas ela funciona no PostgreSQL me retornando a quantidade correta e no SQLite funciona mas me traz dados a mais também, o link é este: https://ghostbin.com/paste/9uqnn   nele eu disponibilizo todo o Banco de Dados por meio de um **INSERT** se tu puder me ajudar agradeço amigo.

Comment: Meu caro, primeiro que eu tinha entendido errado uns detalhes.
O agrupamento que eu falei acima não iria funcionar pq eu não reparei que tinha mais dados que poderiam se repetir(Como a data_ativacao e a data_importacao)

Mas, estranhamente, a resposta seria o que foi feito no link que vc passou.
Um subselect com gsm e um max de data_alteracao, usada em um inner join para limitar os registros retornados.

O exemplo que eu fiz aqui, cheguei a mesma conclusão, mas não pude testar com SQL Server, apenas com postgresql. O SQL abaixo:

Comment: select
 ex.*
from 
 export1 ex 
 inner join (
  select gsm, max(data_alteracao) as max_alteracao
  from export1
  group by gsm
 ) limites on limites.gsm = ex.gsm and ex.data_alteracao = limites.max_alteracao
where ex.gsm = '31994202248'

Comment: gsm = '31994202248' tem 4 registros possíveis, mas o que esta em status = 'LIBERADO' pode ser exibido por ter data maior baseado nos dados do ghostbin.

Comment: fiquei meio perdido, e em relação as outras regras? como **MOTIVO_ENVIO iguais e STATUS iguais?** e você usou `ex.gsm = '31994202248'` pra testar somente aquele GSM? se eu remover está parte irá funcionar? estou meio perdido pois sou iniciante em SQL quero me aprofundar mais, você poderia editar a sua RESPOSTA acrescentando todos os campos para mim testar por favor, e obrigado por está ajudando, foi o único que continuou a tentar ajudar, vlw mesmo.

Comment: Sim. este gsm específico foi o que usei pra teste. Olhei os dados que vc enviou e procurei um gsm que tivesse mais de uma ocorrência pra facilitar a análise e achei este com 4 ocorrências. existem outros, mas eu precisava de 1 pra facilitar. No caso do SQL acima, ele faz um subselect pegando APENAS o GSM e a maior data_alteracao. Após isso, eu uso esses dados para limitar a pesquisa principal e fazer com que só a última ocorrência seja válida. Veja agora o SQL da resposta que eu modifiquei e se atente no comentário dela.

Comment: Apareceu um erro aqui, dizendo assim: no such column: ex2.Nº Tel

Comment: Falha minha, tinha escrito errado o SQL. Reveja a parte do inner. na resposta. Acabo de modificar.

Comment: agora rodou mas infelizmente continua me retornando os mesmos dados que retornava na Query anterior, agradeço a ajuda, mas essa p**** de SQLite tá me tirando só pode, nunca vi isso a mesma Query exibir no PostgreSQL 9 registros e no SQLite 12 registros, infelizmente não deu, vlw pela atenção, vou ficar tomando seu tempo mais não.

Comment: Entendo como é essa frustração. Bom, não sabia que era SQLite então achei melhor testar. Usando o mesmo SQL que consta no https://ghostbin.com/paste/9uqnn e parece correto. Eu estou usando para conectar o driver https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc na versão mais recente c/ DBeaver. Espero que consiga uma solução.